# unique values array in loop

Tags: python, arrays, list

I hope you can help me. I have the follwoing problem.

I have an array made of random numbers. Given a value n, I need to choose the n unique numbers from that array ,and then iterate over it comparing the next element with the previous n unique numbers. 
I have this until now:

```
import random
len1=30
array1=[]
for j in range(1,len1):
     z=random.randint(1,30)
     array1.append(z)
n=5
k=0
l=n
for idx,val in enumerate(array1):    
     if idx>n-1:
         print(val)
         array2=array1[k:l]        
         for p in array2:
             if p == val:
                 #do things
                 ok=1
             else:
                 ok=2
    k=k+1
    l=l+1
```

Overall the behaviour of this routine is good, however it doesn't take into account the uniqueness of the numbers of array2. My question is: How can I have a vector of unique n values extracted from array1? 
Just one condition I cannot look "forward" in the vector. I have to use always a lower index of array1 than the actual idx in the loop.

In another words, if I have n =5 and:

```
 array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]
```

and I am in the idx 8 (i.e =

```
 array2=[3,4,5,6,7] (in any order)
```

Comment: if you need uniqueness and want to check if its in: use a set:  `set(array2)` - there are no dupes in sets. they are unique by definition

Comment: on python 3.x:  `array1=random.choices(range(1,31),k=len1)`  - no loop needed

Comment: I don't generate array1. So it comes with repeated values.

Comment: and yes I was thinking to use let, but I don*t know how to include it so I can do what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, loop through the input `array1` and fill your `array2` up with unique values as you go. If your `array2` gets too long, remove the oldest item from the list.

```
n = 5
arr2 = []
for val in arr1:
    if not arr2:
        arr2.append(val)  # new array case
    else:
        if arr2.count(val):
            arr2.remove(val)  # remove first occurrence (shifts everything ahead of it down one)
            arr2.append(val)  # append val to end
        else:
            arr2.append(val)  # append new unique value
            if len(arr2) > n:
                arr2.pop(0)  # remove oldest value if array is too long
    print(arr2)
```

Run on the example `arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7]`, we get the following sequence of outputs:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
[2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
[3, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```

Comment: ok. It is a good answer, but I am not sure if it will work because I'm using the index of the repeated number.

Comment: @Nikko you are, but you don't need to. This doesn't use it. If you need to collect the indices though instead of the values, just do the same with `for idx, val in enumerate(array1)` and then `append(idx)` instead of `val`.

Comment: yeah you are right, I can add that info. I am implementing your idea in the code. =). Let you know if it works!

Comment: well, it worked but not perfect in the end. I found some misbehavior. I need that if it finds a new repeated value then it should shift the unique old values to the older position were the repeated value was... is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example in the comments? Like step through what it should do for a particular input?

Comment: sure: For example n=5. array = 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,7. Output 1 : 12345, O2: 23456, O3: 23465 (instead of 34565), O4: 23654 (instead of 34654), O5: 36547 ..etc

Comment: @Nikko updated it! I think it does what you are asking for now.